# Mapping actions and state to ReduxForm

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form

I recently upgraded from Redux Form 5.3.1 to Redux Form 6.2 and I've not been able to dispatch my custom action creator on the form submit; it shows up as not a function. The formProps are however, correct when inspected and the handleFormSubmit is called correctly. It's just that it doesn't recognize any actions as mapped to properties.

**Update**

Fairly confident, it's the change in the api of `reduxForm` call. https://github.com/erikras/redux-form/issues/2013

This might be a solution:

https://gist.github.com/insin/bbf116e8ea10ef38447b

The code from Redux Form 6.2:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import * as actions from '../../actions';
import { Field, reduxForm } from 'redux-form';
import InputField from '../input-field/index.js';

class Signup extends Component {
  handleFormSubmit(formProps) {
    // PROBLEM -> Uncaught TypeError: this.props.signupUser is not a function
    this.props.signupUser(formProps);
  }

  render() {
    const { handleSubmit, submitting } = this.props;

    return (
      <form onSubmit={ handleSubmit(this.handleFormSubmit.bind(this)) } >
        <Field name="username" type="text" component={ InputField } label="Username" />
        <Field name="email" type="email" component={ InputField } label="Email" />
        <Field name="password" type="password" component={ InputField } label="Password" />
        <Field name="password_confirmation" type="password" component={ InputField } label="Confirmation" />
        <div>
          <button type="submit" disabled={ submitting }>Submit</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps({ auth }) {
  return { errorMessage: auth.errors };
}

export default reduxForm({
  form: 'signup',
  warn,
  validate
}, mapStateToProps, actions)(Signup);
```

signupUser action creator

```
export function signupUser(props) {
  return dispatch => {
    axios.post(`${apiRoot}users`, { user: { ...props } })
        .then(response => {
          const { status, errors, access_token, username } = response.data;

          if (status === 'created') {
             // handler
          }
          else {
            dispatch(authError(errors));
          }
        })
        .catch(err => dispatch(authError(err.message)));
  }
}
```

Previously working code (5.3.1):

```
class Signup extends Component {
  handleFormSubmit(formProps) {
    this.props.signupUser(formProps);
  }

  render() {
    const {
      handleSubmit,
      fields: {
        email,
        password,
        password_confirmation,
        username,
      }
    } = this.props;

    return (
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.handleFormSubmit.bind(this))}>
          <fieldset className="form-group">
            <label>Username:</label>
            <input className="form-control" {...username} />
            {username.touched && username.error && <div className="error">{username.error}</div>}
          </fieldset>
          <fieldset className="form-group">
            <label>Email:</label>
            <input className="form-control" {...email} />
            {email.touched && email.error && <div className="error">{email.error}</div>}
          </fieldset>
          <fieldset className="form-group">
            <label>Password:</label>
            <input type="password" className="form-control" {...password} />
            {password.touched && password.error && <div className="error">{password.error}</div>}
          </fieldset>
          <fieldset className="form-group">
            <label>Confirm Password:</label>
            <input type="password" className="form-control" {...password_confirmation} />
            {password_confirmation.touched && password_confirmation.error && <div className="error">{password_confirmation.error}</div>}
          </fieldset>
          <button action="submit">Sign up</button>
        </form>
    );
}
```

As you can see, apart from error handling they're very similar. Obviously, it's a major version change, I'm just not seeing why the action creator will be undefined. I attempted to change the `connect` call to use a `mapDispatchToProp` function but had the same result. When I inspect the props by throwing a debugger, none of the functions are mapped to the props. What happened?

Is there a way to capture the form handler submit?  I can't think of a situation where you wouldn't want to capture the form submit.

Answer (score 0):

The 6+ version introduced a change to how the `reduxForm` api works. Instead of it taking the form

```
export default reduxForm({
   form: 'name-of-form',
   fields: ['field1', 'field2'],
   // other configs
}, mapStateToProps, actions)(ComponentName);
```

Instead, you should use the redux `connect` function like this if you want to connect redux properties and actions:

```
const form = reduxForm({
  form: 'name-of-form',
  // other configs
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, actions)(form(ComponentName));
```

This is working for me now.

Answer (score 0):

My way of `connect`ing:

```
 import { connect } from 'react-redux';

 class Signup extends Component {

     // ...

 }

 const SignupForm = reduxForm({
   form: 'signup',
   warn,
   validate
 })(Signup);

 export default connect(
   ({ auth }) => ({
     errorMessage: auth.errors
   }),
   {
     ...actions
   }
 )(SignupForm);
```

Answer (score 0):

The API for `reduxForm()` changed from 5.x to 6.x.

With [5.x](http://redux-form.com/5.3.1/#/api/reduxForm) you use to be able to do exactly what you're doing now:

```
import * as actions from '../../actions';

function mapStateToProps({ auth }) {
  return { errorMessage: auth.errors };
}

export default reduxForm({
  form: 'signup',
  warn,
  validate
}, mapStateToProps, actions)(Signup);
```

With 6.x they only let you pass in the config object. However, the [official redux-form documentation for 6.2.0 (see bottom of page)](http://redux-form.com/6.2.0/examples/initializeFromState/) recommends the following:

```
import * as actions from '../../actions';

function mapStateToProps({ auth }) {
  return { errorMessage: auth.errors };
}

Signup = reduxForm({
  form: 'signup',
  warn,
  validate
})(SupportForm);

export default connect(mapStateToProps, actions)(Signup);
```